# How to apply a texture to a bezier curve?

Tags: texturing, uv, bezier-curves

I'm modeling an open book, so for the curved page I have taken a bezier curve and once I found the proper proportions, I have converted it to a mesh. The problem is that, when applying a texture, it appear stretched and when I try scaling on the UV Editing, it doesn't seem to influence the object. The result of this operations is the following:
[image]
As told previously, the image is the same on the 2 pages, but there is no way to scale it on the left one. Is there any way I can apply properly the image or any method to solve my problem?
As asked in the comments here there is the UV Editor view:
[image]

The link for the file is there: [image]

The image for the page instead is following:
[image]

Comment: Hello, it's a problem of UV, please show the UV Editor, or pack the image and share your file

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded it in the main section after your comment

Comment: Could you please pack the image and share the file?

Comment: I don't know how to share the file

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or use another platform like workupload and same thing, share the link it will generate

Comment: Done as you told me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate*, not the *Generated* output, otherwise it won't take your UV into account but it will use the generated way to project the image:

[image]

Comment: But something strange is going on in the left and right edges, like the texture is curved

Comment: in the Subdivision Surface modifier > Advanced > Uv Smooth, try Keep Corners for example